# Best practice way to access Windows Local Machine Certificate Store from Java?

Tags: java, encryption, java-native-interface, cryptoapi

Trying to access keys stuck in the Windows Certificate Store which are in the Local Machine store. MSCAPI is no help since that only provides access to the Current User and Root stores. Is there a known best-practice way of getting to the Local Machine store?

Everything I can find on this issue - like [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612962/access-local-machine-certificate-store-in-java) - is at least a few years out of date. Is JNI inevitable here?

Comment: The question you've linked to is an exact duplicate of this question, so I have chosen to close your question. I've added a 100-rep bounty to the other one, in the hopes of attracting a better and updated answer.

Comment: Although it occurs to me that the other question was about servlets, so perhaps I've made a mistake by closing this one... I suspect the answers will be identical though. I've reopened this, but take a look at the other question and you might get an answer there.

Comment: No, the other question would have been sufficient if it was up-to-date. Thanks for adding the bounty!